# Modeling RealEstate hierarchical location using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am designing a Real Estate classifieds website. Each ad will have a location which will defined using the following three attributes (state, city, town).

What's the best way to represent this in a Mongodb document? I am worrying about query performance because:

1. Location will be the first search criteria
2. I want to allow users to search by multiple locations.

**Example:** A user looking to rent a flat in New York (state) or in Harrisburg (city in Pennsylvania).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I will use regular expressions like the following:

```
db.ads.find({$or:[{location: /^,new york/},{location: /^,pennsylvania,harrisburg,/}]})
```

This solution was inspired from [the following article](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/)